# Self-Study: Laplace Transform $\sin(t)$ Different Results for Different Approaches

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning, laplace-transform

I calculated the Laplace Transform $\mathcal{L}\{sin(t)\}$ using the complexification of the integral and using the linearity property in combination with $\mathcal{L}\{e^{iat}\} = \frac{1}{s-ia}$ and get different results.

The second approach is takeing from [Wiki Proofs](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laplace_Transform_of_Sine) and is rather short:

Because: $\mathcal{L}\{af(t) + bg(t)\} = a\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} + b\mathcal{L}\{g(t)\}$ and $\mathcal{L}\{e^{iat}\} = \frac{1}{s-ia}$:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{e^{iat}\} &= \mathcal{L}\{\cos(t) + i\sin(t)\} = \mathcal{L}\{\cos(t)\} + i\mathcal{L}\{\sin(t)\} \\
&\Rightarrow \mathcal{L}\{\sin(t)\} = IM(\mathcal{L}\{e^{iat}\}) = IM(\frac{s+ia}{s^2 + a^2}) = \frac{a}{s^2 + a^2}
\end{align}
$$

Thus when $a = 1 \Rightarrow \mathcal{L}\{\sin(t)\} = \frac{1}{s^2 + 1}$.

However, when I calculate $\mathcal{L}\{\sin(t)\}$ using the complexification of the sine, I get the following result:

$$
\begin{align}
\int e^{-st}\sin(t)dt &= IM(\int e^{-st}e^{it}dt) = IM(\int e^{(i - s)t} dt) \\
                     &= IM(\frac{e^{(i - s)t}}{i-s}) = IM(\frac{i+s}{(i-s)(i+s)}e^{-st}e^{it}) \\
                     &= \frac{1}{1 + s^2}e^{-st}IM((i+s)(\cos(t) + i\sin(t)) \\
                     &= \frac{1}{1 + s^2}e^{-st}IM(i(\cos(t) + i\sin(t)) + s(\cos(t) + i\sin(t))) \\
                     &= \frac{1}{1 + s^2}e^{-st}IM(i\cos(t) + i^2\sin(t)) + s\cos(t) + is\sin(t))) \\
                     &= \frac{1}{1 + s^2}e^{-st}IM(i(\cos(t) + s\sin(t)) + (s\cos(t)-\sin(t)))\\
                     &= \frac{1}{1 + s^2}e^{-st}(\cos(t) + s\sin(t))\\
\end{align}
$$

Putting all together:

$$
\frac{1}{1 + s^2}e^{-st}(\cos(t) + s\sin(t)) = \frac{1}{s^2 + 1} \Rightarrow e^{-st}(\cos(t) + s\sin(t)) = 1
$$

is that correct? If not, where is my mistake?

**EDIT**

I followed these two sources for the complexification:

[Complexifying the Integral (Arthur Mattuck, MIT)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CpM1jJ0lob8&t=449s)
[The dessert, complexifying the integral](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0C70WQDHNg)

where the latter calculates: $\int e^{-bx}sin(x)dx$ and the former $\int e^{-x}cos(x)dx$

Comment: There is no integration variable $t$ to be found outside the integral or after integration. You need to explcitly apply the integration interval.

Comment: The Laplace transform is the definite integral $\int_0^\infty$, not an antiderivative...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get unexpected results, first be more strict with the symbolism you employ. Here it is the integration interval and the integration variable $t$ that is bound to it.
\begin{align}
{\cal L}\{\sin t\}(s)&=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\sin t\,dt=\text{Im}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{(i-s)t}\,dt\right)
\\
&=\text{Im}\left(\left[\frac{e^{(i-s)t}}{i-s}\right]_{t=0}^\infty\right)
=\text{Im}\left(\frac{0-1}{i-s}\right)
\end{align}
for $s>0$, which then gives the correct result.